# Stacking Graphs LogiXML

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql

I am trying to stack bar graphs up as in the picture below.  My data layer is returning several values for a particular date, which corresponds to different 'codes'. However, when using `Chart.XY` element and feeding the data to Logi, the X-axis repeats the date for every different element (or 'code) and not stacking them properly.  I believe there is something fundamental I'm doing wrong, but cannot find out what (Extra bar option set to 'Stacked'). Any help is appreciated!

This is the graph:

[image: graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may not be possible to create the exact chart you need using a single Chart.XY element.  ExtraGrid Layers don't support multi-series, so you can't currently layer 2 multi-series charts on top of each other.  The best option might be to build multiple charts each with it's own multi-series using a Crosstab filter.

Here's a quick example of a similar chart to your example produced with 'static' data with the Crosstab filter.

```
<Chart Type="XY" XYChartType="Bar" ChartHeight="300" ChartWidth="500" ChartOrientation="Horizontal" Color="#66C2A5,#FC8D62,#8DA0CB,#E78AC3" ChartLabelColumn="Item" ChartLabelColumnDataType="Text" Transparency="4">
  <DataLayer Type="Static" ID="staticDL1">
    <StaticDataRow Item="F" BudgetQuarter="Q1" BudgetValue="65" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="F" BudgetQuarter="Q2" BudgetValue="55" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="F" BudgetQuarter="Q3" BudgetValue="45" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="F" BudgetQuarter="Q4" BudgetValue="60" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="E" BudgetQuarter="Q1" BudgetValue="45" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="E" BudgetQuarter="Q2" BudgetValue="55" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="E" BudgetQuarter="Q3" BudgetValue="65" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="E" BudgetQuarter="Q4" BudgetValue="70" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="A" BudgetQuarter="Q1" BudgetValue="65" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="A" BudgetQuarter="Q2" BudgetValue="55" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="A" BudgetQuarter="Q3" BudgetValue="45" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="A" BudgetQuarter="Q4" BudgetValue="60" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="B" BudgetQuarter="Q1" BudgetValue="45" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="B" BudgetQuarter="Q2" BudgetValue="55" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="B" BudgetQuarter="Q3" BudgetValue="65" />
    <StaticDataRow Item="B" BudgetQuarter="Q4" BudgetValue="70" />
    <CrosstabFilter CrosstabColumn="BudgetQuarter" CrosstabLabelColumn="Item" CrosstabValueColumn="BudgetValue" CrosstabValueFunction="Sum" />
  </DataLayer>
  <Legend />
</Chart>
```

You can build 2 of these charts, one for your Budget and one for Actual.   Depending on how the data is structured, you might also be able to use Extra Data Columns/Extra Grid Layers to build a more complex chart.

For more details on Crosstab charts, you might want to take a look at the Sample application for static charts:

http://devnet.logixml.com/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=Samples
Specifically, looking at the Crosstab filter :

http://devnet.logixml.com/SampleCharts/rdPage.aspx?rdReport=CrosstabFilter

Comment: Absolutely solved my problem!!! I had added a Crosstab filter but wasn't inputting the correct data values, your example was the key!